# Google Spreadsheet Autofill column based rows

Tags: google-sheets, autofill

I have 2 sheets. The first called "Total" and the second called "May".
In Total sheet,I have a column with "expenses" (Shopping, Fuel, Coffee), and a column with "month" (May):
[Total sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShG0t.png)

In the "May" sheet, I have Columns with the expenses details:
[May Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtkd6.png)

I'm trying to get the total of the expenses in the "Total" sheet, so at B2 at "Total" sheet I entered `=SUM(May!A:A)`.
The problem is when I'm dragging down the cell to the next rows, I'm not getting

```
=SUM(May!B:B)
```

but instead I'm getting duplication of the cell.
It's possible to fill the rows automatically as I expected?
Is there a better way to to it (maybe not "SUM" formula at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FILTER()` to select the appropriate column of data and then `SUM()` that. Just put the following in `B2` for your May sheet:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D:F, D$1:F$1 = A2))
```

... and then drag the formula downwards.

Comment: Thanks. It’s not possible to do it otherwise? Maybe with another formulas?

Comment: It certainly is. I've added an example using `FILTER()`. Happy spreadsheeting!